# change string in TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm try to write program for searching smallest word in the input string using this algorithm.

My Algorithm:

```
Read character from input, but not echo
If character is space:
    current_string_length = 0;
    current_string = "";
    echo character
Else If character belong to English alphabet:
    current_string_length++;
    current_string += character;
    if current_string_length < max_string_length:
       max_string = current_string;
       max_string_length = current_length_string;
    echo character
Else If character is "\n":
    print max_string
```

But i'm new in assembly and can't find way to add character to string and clean string. How can i do this, or maybe i need to choose different algorithm for this task?

My code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h                             ; reserves 100h bytes for stack

.data
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
; Variables
maxString           db 128 dup('$') 
currentString       db 128 dup('$')
maxLength           dw 0
currentLength       dw 0
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
; Messages
helloMessage  db 10,13,'Assembly Shortest Word Finder Version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2016 RodionSoft',10,13,10,13,'Usage: enter string with length of words not more then 128 characters',10,13,10,13,10,13,10,13,'Enter string: $'
resultMessage db 10,13,"Shortest word: $"
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
; Program
.code
start :
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Print helloMessage
    lea dx, helloMessage                ; LEA - Load Affective Address 
    mov ah, 9                           ; print the string of the adress 
    int 21h                             ; present in DX register


;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; main loop
    repeat:
        ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ; Read character but not echo
        mov ah, 08h                     
        int 21h
        mov ah, 0                       ; ah = 0

        cmp al, 13h                     ; if(al == enter)
        jz printResult                  ;   printResult()
        cmp al, 20h                     ; if(al == enter)   
        jz spaceinput                   ;   spaceInput()
        ; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cmp al, 41h                     ; if(al < 'A')
        jl badInput                     ;   badInput()
        cmp al, 7Ah                     ; if(al > 'z')
        jg badInput                     ;   badInput()
        cmp al, 5Bh                     ; if(al < '[')
        jg goodInput                    ;   goodInput()
        cmp al, 60h                     ; if(al > '`')
        jg goodInput                    ;   goodInput()
        jmp badInput                    ; else badInput()

        goodInput:
            inc currentString
            ; currentString += al


        badInput:
            jmp repeat

        spaceInput:
            mov currentLength, 0
            ;clean currentString

        endOfIteration:
            mov ah, 2                       ; echo
            int 21h
            jmp repeat                      ; loop
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
printResult:
    lea dx, secondMessage               
    mov ah, 9                           
    int 21h 
    lea dx, maxString               
    mov ah, 9                           
    int 21h 
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
exit:
    MOV AX, 4c00h
    INT 21h

StringComparison proc 
    push cx dx bx ax bp si di           ; save general-purpose registers    

    mov cx, maxLength                   ; cx = maxLength
    mov dx, currentLength               ; dx = currentLength
    cmp cx, dx                          ; if(currentLength > maxLength)
    jl currentBigger                    ;   currentBigger()
    jmp return                          ; else return

    currentBigger:
        ; maxString = currentString
    return:
    pop di si bp ax bx dx cx            ; restore general-purpose registers
    ret 
endp
end start
```

Comment: That algorithm looks quite wrong to me in many ways... Let's pretend it's loop body, and you initialized all values ahead, and let's say I would input a, b, _, c, \n ... Then the algorithm would output: a, b, _, c, a. (it would be probably good to display \n, and shortest string is "c", not "a")... So you need to fix the algorithm for this task first, and considering how some fix may look, it will be quite close to changing it, but not because of string append and clear, those can stay.

Comment: Maybe try to not write algorithm in C-like first, but go even one abstraction level higher, ie "I will find shortest word" -> "found=none, parse input for words, for each word when smaller than found, then found = word" -> .... splitting it down to simpler steps, and validating from time to time on various inputs it's OK. (consider not only common like "ab c\n" and "a bc\n", but also tricky like "\n" and "  \n".

Comment: Thank you, i will try to refactoring this algorithm. But how i can do staff like adding character to string and clean variable which contain current word with assembly language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't find way to add character to string and clean string.

Well, in the first place it depends on your definition of what is string (this is common theme in assembly, deciding how you store your data, ie. which bits/bytes are used for what and what meaning you give them).

Look for example at `resultMessage`. It's composed of consecutive bytes with ASCII encoded values, ending with value `'$'` used as terminator for the DOS service.

In C/C++ the classic string literal is similar, but for terminator the value `0` is used.

In (old 16b) Pascal the first byte contains length 0-255 of string, following "length" bytes contain the ASCII letters, there's no terminator at end.

In Linux the system call to display string to console takes the pointer to the letters as in DOS/C definitions, but without any terminator, the length of string has to be provided aside as second argument, and it's up to programmer how he will get it.

So, such simple thing as string, and you have already 4 different ways how to store it in memory.

But in your case you don't need to work only with final string, but build it up and alter it, so probably the easiest way is to allocate some memory byte array:   `currentString       db 128 dup('$')`

And to keep `end()` pointer in some register, let's say `si`.

Then common tasks can be achieved like this:

```
; all callable subroutines bellow expect the register "si"
; to point beyond last character of currentString
; (except the clearString of course, which works always)

appendLetterInAL:
    cmp     si,OFFSET currentString+127 ; 127 to have one byte for '$'
    jae     appendLetterInAL_bufferIsFull_Ignore
    mov     [si],al  ; store new letter after previous last
    inc     si       ; update "si" to point to new end()
appendLetterInAL_bufferIsFull_Ignore:
    ret

clearString:         ; works also as INIT at the start of code
    lea     si,[currentString]
    ret

prepareStringForDOSOutput:
    mov     BYTE PTR [si],'$'  ; set terminator at end()
    lea     dx,[currentString] ; dx = pointer to string
    ret

getLengthOfString:  ; sets cx to length of current string
    ; lea     cx,[si - currentString] ; probably not allowed in 16b?
    ; other variant
    mov     cx,si
    sub     cx,OFFSET currentString
    ret

copyCurrentStringToDI:
  ; copies current string to buffer @di
  ; and also terminates it in DOS way with '$'
  ; upon return di contains original value
    push    bx
    lea     bx,[currentString]
    push    di
copyCurrentStringToDI_loop:
    cmp     bx,si      ; all bytes copied
    jae     copyCurrentStringToDI_finish
    mov     al,[bx]
    inc     bx
    mov     [di],al
    inc     di
    jmp     copyCurrentStringToDI_loop
copyCurrentStringToDI_finish:
    mov     BYTE PTR [di],'$'  ; set DOS terminator
    pop     di                 ; restore di to original value
    pop     bx                 ; restore also bx
    ret
```

So basically two pointers (current end() in `si`, and the start of string being fixed at compile time as `currentString`) are enough to do many manipulations with it.

I hope the algorithms and used data structure is easy to understand from the code and comments.

Comment: Example usage: `call clearString` `call prepareStringForDOSOutput` `mov ah,9` `int 21h` should output empty string (ie. nothing at all).

Comment: Example 2: `call clearString` `mov al,'x'` `call appendLetterInAL` `call prepareStringForDOSOutput` `mov ah,9` `int 21h` should output "x".

Comment: Thank you very much for answers @Ped7g! But one more question what usage of copyCurrentStringToDI, and if i need to watch for length of shortest string, and change its value on value of currentString, am i need to duplicate this code and use some register as si in currentString ?

Comment: In your original algorithm, where you found new shortest string, you may want to store it somewhere, like `lea di,[maxString]` `call copyCurrentStringToDI`. At the start of program you can put into it string "no word found$", then at exit you just display `maxString` buffer. I didn't understand the other part of question, IMO you don't need any second string for your original task, but in case you need second append+all string buffer, then having duplicated code is one of possible solutions (not very smart one). Other is to change this code to work in more flexible way (struct in mem? stack?).

Comment: @Robin: generally you are the king of the CPU, you can do whatever calculation you wish and can describe exactly enough in terms of instructions. At human level you need clear idea what is the initial set of numbers you are calculating at and what is the calculation itself. Then you try to write it in instructions as directly as possible. All the cruft around like init/save reg/call is usually by-product of that. In your task you get one array of bytes with ASCII letters forming words split by 32 (space), ended by 13 (`\n`), you store the numbers, count numbers between 32/13, and keep shortest